# How can I load all week days, between a start date and an end date, to a Data Frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a simple routine that adds all dates, between a start date and end date, to a dataframe.

```
import datetime

begin = datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date(2019, 1, 10)

weekdays = []

next_day = begin
while True:
    if next_day > end:
        break
    print(next_day)
    next_day += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    weekdays.append(str(next_day))
dfwk = pd.DataFrame(weekdays)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add only weekdays to the datframe.  Also, I'm trying to figure out how to add the names of the days of the week.  How can I do this?  Basically, I want a dateframe that looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the working days by date_range:

```
import pandas as pd

datetime_index = pd.date_range('2018-07-20', '2018-08-19', freq=pd.tseries.offsets.BDay()).tolist()
weekday_name = [d.strftime('%A') for d in datetime_index]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(datetime_index, weekday_name)), columns=['date', 'day name'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Menglong Li.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I just learned how to use the zip function this past weekend.  I like it a lot.  I will be using that a lot more in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to solve your question using `date` and `timedelta` from `datetime` module:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

def next_day(begin, end):
    """Generator that returns the date and date's weekday name"""

    while begin < end:
        # If you need the first day
        # uncomment the next line and comment the next yield one
        # yield begin, begin.strftime('%A')
        begin += timedelta(days=1)
        yield begin, begin.strftime('%A')


begin = date(2018, 1, 1)
end = date(2019, 1, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame(next_day(begin, end), columns=['date', 'day name'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           date   day name
0    2018-01-02    Tuesday
1    2018-01-03  Wednesday
2    2018-01-04   Thursday
3    2018-01-05     Friday
4    2018-01-06   Saturday
5    2018-01-07     Sunday
6    2018-01-08     Monday
7    2018-01-09    Tuesday
8    2018-01-10  Wednesday
9    2018-01-11   Thursday
10   2018-01-12     Friday
...
368  2019-01-05   Saturday
369  2019-01-06     Sunday
370  2019-01-07     Monday
371  2019-01-08    Tuesday
372  2019-01-09  Wednesday
373  2019-01-10   Thursday
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding your dates to a list of `(date, weekdayname)`, then converting to a dataframe at the end:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

from calendar import day_name

begin = date(2018, 1, 1)
end = date(2019, 1, 10)

# Get difference between dates
delta = end - begin

dates = []

# Only iterate through dates between
for i in range(1, delta.days):

    # Get next date with timedelta()
    next_date = begin + timedelta(i)

    # Append next date and weekday name
    dates.append((next_date, day_name[next_date.weekday()]))

# Convert to dataframe
df = DataFrame(dates, columns=['date', 'weekdayname'])
print(df)
```

Which gives something like:

```
           date weekdayname
0    2018-01-02     Tuesday
1    2018-01-03   Wednesday
2    2018-01-04    Thursday
3    2018-01-05      Friday
4    2018-01-06    Saturday
5    2018-01-07      Sunday
6    2018-01-08      Monday
7    2018-01-09     Tuesday
8    2018-01-10   Wednesday
9    2018-01-11    Thursday
10   2018-01-12      Friday
11   2018-01-13    Saturday
12   2018-01-14      Sunday
13   2018-01-15      Monday
14   2018-01-16     Tuesday
15   2018-01-17   Wednesday
...
```

**Note:** The above assumes that the start and end dates are exclusive. If you want them to be inclusive, use `range(delta.days + 1)` instead.